# UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther Vs UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
//my code
}
```

Currently my above delegate method is called, once i touch inside in my webview.

So i want to know what is the difference between following 2 navigationtype: `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` & `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`.

Because some of the URL on selection provides navigation Type as `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` & some provide `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`.

From the apple document i cannot able to clear my self.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked` happens if the user taps a `<a href="">` style link, if the change is done from within Javascript (`onclick` event for example) `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` is used.

Furthermore `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` is used if you first load a page or you'll be redirected by a meta refresh or something

Comment: Is there a way to identify whether UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther is sent to delegate call as a result of redirection or window.open()?